# "If a drop of oil is placed in a glass of water, it __ to the top."

Tags: tense, modality

> If a drop of oil is placed in a glass of water, it _______ to the top.
>
> A. will float
>   B. would float
>   C. does float
>   D. should float

I pick C, but several people picked A.

In my opinion, this sentence belongs to conditional sentence type 0 so in the main clause, we should use present simple tense. We can use emphasis on the verb “float” and it doesn’t affect, does it?
In emphasis grammar, we can replace “floats” with “does float”. Why does nobody accept C?

Comment: The simple present would be the enduring present (a statement of fact that has been true, is true, and will continue to be true). A is correct for a logical proposition. C is correct for an emphatic statement to (for example) convince someone who doesn't believe that oil floats on water. D is correct for someone not quite sure whether oil floats on water.

Answer (score 1):

All of them except B are grammatical, but A is "best". There's no apparent reason to give emphasis, so C is out of place.